# Как работает функция trim в данном случае?

Tags: php

Есть код

```
<?php

$a = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15);
$b = implode('', $a);
$r = trim($b, '15');
echo $r;
?>
```

Можно пояснить почему результатом будет 234 ?

Comment: Оно убирает символы 1 и 5

Comment: удаляет все единички и пятерки http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php

Comment: я тоже так думал, но если $r = trim($b, '14'); то результатом будет 234515 . Четвёрка почему-то остаётся.

Comment: @Sven  Неправильно задан вопрос!:) Вот, если бы вы спросили, какой будет результат, тогда интереснее. Когда вы уже сообщили ответ, то каждый вам скажет, что удаляются символы 1 и 5 из строки.:)

Comment: Так а что на самом деле проиходит? как оно работает то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно описанию, найденному в интернет:),

> The trim() function is used to remove the white spaces and other
>   predefined characters from the **left and right sides** of a string.
>   Specifies the character(s) to remove. Without this remove the
>   following " " an ordinary space

функция `trim` удаляет начальные и конечные символы  согласно заданному шаблону в виде строки. Например, для фрагмента кода

```
$a = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15);
$b = implode('', $a);
$r = trim($b, '14');
```

будут удалены начальные '1' И в резуьтате получится

```
'234515'
```

Символы '4' и '1', которые находятся внутри строки, не будут удалены, так как они не является начальным или завершающим символом строки.

А для данного фрагмента код

```
$a = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15);
$b = implode('', $a);
$r = trim($b, '15');
```

будет результат

```
'234'
```

Comment: аа...вот теперь понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: в примечании на русском это все есть :) http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php